# Get a list of posts by specific category

Tags: wp-query, query, search

I'm trying to build a search query in PHP in WordPress and I need to get all posts by a specific author in a specific category including drafts.

For example, is it possible to do something like, "status=draft and author=12 and category=7"?

Also, I haven't been able to find the page that shows how to build WordPress query.

Note: I'm using the [JSON-API](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) plug-in and using it's [get_search_results](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/) method. It's not clear if it's a full WP_Query like search since "cat=1" and "author=1" does not return results but "demo" and other common keywords return posts.

Comment: You should try and search it in the site with keywords and I am sure you will find plenty of answer related to your question.

Comment: you can try using [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters) class for this.

Comment: I was trying to use the JSON-API plug-in and use it's "get_search_results" API. I don't think it's the same as WP_Query which our friend linked below. I say this because it finds posts by keywords but when I enter a search like, "cat=1" or "author=1" as described on that page it does not show any results.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following query for getting the results if you have `author_id`, `post_status` and `cat_id` with you.

```
global $wpdb;

$author_id = 1;

$cat_id = 1;

$post_status = 'publish';

/*  Post Titles  */

$search_titles = $wpdb->get_col(        
                "SELECT DISTINCT post_title FROM $wpdb->posts
                LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON
                ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
                LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON
                ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
                WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = '$post_status'
                AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_author = $author_id
                AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
                AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $cat_id"        
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'cat'              => 7,
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => array('publish', 'draft', 'pending' ),
    'author'           => 1,
); 

$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $postslist as $post ) :
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?> 
    <div>
        <?php the_date(); ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>   
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
<?php
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Replace the category id in 'cat', author id in 'author' and check.
Refer: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query